# k means using numpy - calculate error of each iteration

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, k-means

I am trying to to perform an image quantization (reducing the number of colors of an image) using one of the k-means algorithms of numpy/scipy for a school project. The algirithm works fine, but I also want to calculate the sum of error for each iteration of the algorithm, e.i. the sum of distances of samples to their closest cluster center (this is one of the project tasks).
I could't find any kmeans method of numpy or other fast, elegant way do perform this. 
Is there such a way or method, and if not, what is the best way to perform this task? my goal is to minimize any re-implimentation of the existing kmeans algorithm.

Below I added my code so far

```
import scipy.cluster.vq as vq

def quantize_rgb(im_orig, n_quant, n_iter):
    """
    A function that performs optimal quantization of a given RGB image.
    :param im_orig: the input RGB image to be quantized (float32 image with values in [0, 1])
    :param n_quant: the number of intensities the output image should have
    :param n_iter: the maximum number of iterations of the optimization procedure (may converge earlier.)
    """
    reshaped_im = im_orig.reshape(im_orig.shape[0] * im_orig.shape[1], 3)
    centroids, label = vq.kmeans2(reshaped_im, n_quant, n_iter)
    reshaped_im = centroids[label]
    im_quant = reshaped_im.reshape(im_orig.shape[0], im_orig.shape[1], 3)

    return im_quant
```

Comment: Look at this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: The problem is that this class can't tell me the error of each iteration, only the error of the final result...

Comment: Aaah OK. Hmm... I'm sorry never done this. I'm sure `scikit` has something that could at least be a starting point. If it does not then I'm afraid no other library does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
vq.kmeans2(k=previous_centers, iter=1, minit="matrix")
```

to only do **one iteration at a time**.

Comment: Great! At first I rejected this solution becouse I thought kmeans always use random initiation points, but the `minit="matrix"` solve this problem beautifully.